# Can't use custom font in WebView

Tags: android, css, fonts, webview, android-webview

I have a webview in my application where the body text need to be rendered with the "Times New Roman" font. First of all i have put the .ttf file in my Assets folder.

[image: assets]

I have modified my style.css file to the folowing:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
    src: url("Times-New-Roman.ttf");
}

#body{
    font-family: "Times New Roman",Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 8px;
}
```

And i create my WebView like this:

```
WebView webView = new WebView(activity.getApplicationContext());
String child = "<html><head><link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"style.css\"><body>Test</body></html>";
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", child, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
return webView;
```

But still when the WebView is rendered its in the default Android font and not Times New Roman. I dont know if it matters but i copied the font form my /Library/Fonts folder on my MacBook and just renamed it with "-" instaid of spaces.

Comment: do you see the other styles in the CSS being applied (the 8px font size, for example)? Also, what version of Android are you running on?

Comment: Yes qsasq. All the other styles seems to be applied but not the font. Im using Android 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. By removing the # before body in the CSS i got it to work. If someone who knows HTML better than me sees this could you please give a description to why this works?

Comment: `#body` means you are targeting an ID. e.g.:- `<body id="body">`. in your case, you dont have a id in the body tag. And you only have to refer the `<body>` tag